# How to make PHP go fine with HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, row

I have a index.php page  Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zME5.jpg

Website : http://www.vestigedayz.com/sala/clienti/index.php  (User: Test123, pass: test)

```
 <?php include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages )

      $dbhost = 'host';
   $dbuser = 'user';
   $dbpass = 'pass';
     $conn = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");

     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);


if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("vestiged_sala")) {
    echo "Unable to select vestiged_sala: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

mysql_select_db("vestiged_sala");  

$result = mysql_query("select * from users");

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Antrenor"];
    echo $row["PrimulContract"];
    echo $row["ExpiraContract"];
}


mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

ok, after that it comes HTML codes. I have this code

```
<h4>Bun venit, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> !
    <hr>
    Abonamentul tau expira pe data de: <?php echo $row["ExpiraContract"]; ?> 
    <hr>
    Primul tau contract a fost facut pe data de : <?php echo $row["PrimulContract"];  ?>
    <hr>
    Pe data de <?php echo $row["antrenor"];  ?>  va trebui sa platesti instructorul !
    </h4>
```

But php won't show those rows. Only [user] row. The others it appears to be blank.  When I add     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) above of "Abonamentul tau" it gives me errors.  What is the solution to my problem ? Because I know is something easy but I'm beginner and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Then it means your `$row` does not contain indexes like `ExpiraContract` or your `$row` is entirely empty.

Comment: what rows you have added in user table? did you add ExpiraContract, PrimulContract, etc. in your user table?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source for errors or anomalies?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas  Look a photo here. http://i.imgur.com/UBorPdE.png   it's not empty. I modified the code and if I make it to show in <php> section, it shows. But not in the html.

Comment: @Sunny  Yes. http://i.imgur.com/UBorPdE.png   you can see that it shows, but not where I want.  ( I've modified the code and put those $rows in php part)

Comment: @JasonD  HTML works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok @AlxTioltisan, Can you show the rows of your users table?

Comment: @sunny  http://i.imgur.com/Ay2pWwn.png     It's varchar(50)   as text.

Comment: Let's do this. Write `var_dump($row); exit;` and show us what you get. :)

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas  it gives me NULL http://i.imgur.com/wA5Rt2e.png    (I've added 4 new lines to PHP part to show you that ROWS are visible, but not if I apply them to <html> part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in place of this line

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from users");
```

put these lines

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $expire = $row['ExpiraContract'];
            $primul = $row['PrimulContract'];
            $antrenor = $row['Antrenor'];
    }
```

But remember you have to declare empty variables before these line

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$expire = '';
$primul = '';
$antrenor = '';
```

So, your full code is like this

```
//First define empty variables
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$expire = '';
$primul = '';
$antrenor = '';

// add these lines in place of $result query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $expire = $row['ExpiraContract'];
            $primul = $row['PrimulContract'];
            $antrenor = $row['Antrenor'];
    }
```

This is you html now

```
Abonamentul tau expira pe data de: <?php echo $expire; ?> 
    <hr>
    Primul tau contract a fost facut pe data de : <?php echo $primul;  ?>
    <hr>
    Pe data de <?php echo $antrenor;  ?>  va trebui sa platesti instructorul !
    </h4>
```

Try this. If you have any problem then comment it. :)

Remove these lines if you try this first

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Antrenor"];
    echo $row["PrimulContract"];
    echo $row["ExpiraContract"];
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/vestiged/public_html/sala/clienti/index.php on line 30
   img of code : http://i.imgur.com/BMSsCfm.png

Comment: Ohh sorry! use mysql_fetch_array($result) instead of mysqli. see code now

Comment: Now it gives me unexpected end.  I'm searching for unclosed tags.

Comment: Done. It works FINE. Thank you.  Another question. How can I make Pe data de <?php echo $antrenor;  ?>  va trebui sa platesti instructorul !
     to appear " Nu ai antrenor"   if the $antrenor value is 0 on the database ?

Comment: for this you can use if else condition in php something like if($antrenor == 0) { $antrenor = "Nu ai antrenor";} try this it's fun :P

Comment: worked, but I want to remove the HTML too.  Because it's : On the date [$echo] you will repay the trainer.       and now it comes On the date [You don't own trainer ] will repay the trainer.  Haha. I need to rewrite the html? And how to color the $echo ? i can use html style color?

Comment: Hmm.. do it on your own hahahahha

Comment: haha. Thanks a lot anyway, it helped a lot. I did not understand anything from tutorials.